# regular expression to split a string with comma outside parentheses with more than one level python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like this in python

```
filter="eq(Firstname,test),eq(Lastname,ltest),OR(eq(ContactID,12345),eq(ContactID,123456))"
    rx_comma = re.compile(r"(?:[^,(]|\([^)]*\))+")
    result = rx_comma.findall(filter)
```

Actual result is:

```
['eq(Firstname,test)', 'eq(Lastname,ltest)', 'OR(eq(ContactID,12345)', 'eq(ContactID,123456))']
```

Expected result is:

```
['eq(Firstname,test)', 'eq(Lastname,ltest)', 'OR(eq(ContactID,12345),eq(ContactID,123456))']
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This syntax is to hard for regex parsing, consider using dedicated libraries or writing your own. That said, you can get something that might seem to work with PyPi regex module, but this feels like the wrong path.

Comment: I have tried of using so many syntaxes, but none worked. The syntax is working if it doesn't have nested parenthesis :'(?:[^,(]|\([^)]*\))+'.

Comment: For the current input, a simple `re` regex like `,(?=[^()]*\)|\w+\()` might work. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3CbE7j/2).

Comment: Thank you for the help. It didn't work. It is finding each comma delimiter, instead I want split with comma which is outside parenthesis and it should ignore the comma even in nested parenthesis

Comment: But your expected results say something different. Do you want [this](https://tio.run/##Xc09C8IwEAbgvb/iyHTXBsHPQZAOiiCKio5@QJGogZrU5AaF/veYWiff5eB5j7vqzXdr@iHoR2Udg1M39Uo8TECoJ86182yKh5KsPJOMtCp@Ura02WHUqTVcXHgxk91efzD8bv7ZiEgkV@vgBdq0fzq@KjWjE3hEzMeHM9Ipy2rMu0TpkQjT/XKxjWNOtRQSPI0TiNHX5ogHYxnW1qhWm1ROG8bYUggf)? See https://regex101.com/r/lLXKrw/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you can use the code like

```py
import regex
s = "eq(Firstname,test),eq(Lastname,ltest),OR(eq(ContactID,12345),eq(ContactID,123456))"
for x in regex.split(r"(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|,", s):
    if x is not None:
        print( x )
```

Output:

```
eq(Firstname,test)
eq(Lastname,ltest)
OR(eq(ContactID,12345),eq(ContactID,123456))
```

See the [Python](https://tio.run/##Xc09C8IwEAbgvb/iyHTXBsHPQZAOiiCKio5@QJGogZrU5AaF/veYWiff5eB5j7vqzXdr@iHoR2Udg1M39Uo8TECoJ86182yKh5KsPJOMtCp@Ura02WHUqTVcXHgxk91efzD8bv7ZiEgkV@vgBdq0fzq@KjWjE3hEzMeHM9Ipy2rMu0TpkQjT/XKxjWNOtRQSPI0TiNHX5ogHYxnW1qhWm1ROG8bYUggf) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lLXKrw/1).

*Details*:

- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))` - Group 1 capturing a string between nested paired parentheses
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - the match is skipped and the next match is searched for from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `,` -  a comma.

Answer (score 2):

The OP's issue was already solved by using the `regex` module though, I'd like to introduce [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) as an alternative solution here. It can be installed by the following command:

```sh
pip install pyparsing
```

### Code:

```py
import pyparsing as pp
s = "eq(Firstname,test),eq(Lastname,ltest),OR(eq(ContactID,12345),eq(ContactID,123456))"
expr = pp.delimited_list(pp.original_text_for(pp.Regex(r'.*?(?=\()') + pp.nested_expr('(', ')')))
output = expr.parse_string(s).as_list()
assert output == ['eq(Firstname,test)', 'eq(Lastname,ltest)', 'OR(eq(ContactID,12345),eq(ContactID,123456))']
```

### Explanation:

The key point is the `expr` in the above code. I added some explanatory comments to its definition as follows:

```py
pp.delimited_list( # Separate a given string at the default comma delimiter
    pp.original_text_for( # Get original text instead of completely parsed elements.
        pp.Regex(r'.*?(?=\()') # Search everything before the first opening parenthesis '('
        + pp.nested_expr('(', ')') # Parse nested parentheses
    )
)
```